# Multiple logins with same username Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using Zend\Authentication to authenticate users and am inserting session_id() with every login, but it is still letting multiple logins with the same username. I've tried everything but am at a total loss of how to fix this. Here is my code for checking and inserting sessions:

```
 public function indexAction()
 {

       $user = $this->identity();

       if ($this->getMembersTable()->checkSession($user->username) === false) {
           $_SESSION = array();
           session_destroy();
           setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 300, '/', '', 0);

           return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/auth/login');
       }


    if (null === $user || empty($user)) {
        return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/auth/login');
    } 

    return array('user' => $user);
}


public function checkSession($username)<br>
{

    $sql = new Sql($this->table_gateway->getAdapter());<br>

    $adapter = $sql->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection();

    $query = $adapter->execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE username = 
         '$username' AND session_id = '" . md5(session_id()) . "'");

    if ($query->count() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}

 public function insertSession($username, $password)
 {

    $sql = new Sql($this->table_gateway->getAdapter());


    $insert = new Insert('sessions');

    $adapter = $this->table_gateway->getAdapter();

    $insert->columns(array('username', 'password', 'active', 'session_id'))
      ->values(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1, 'session_id' => md5(session_id())));

    $adapter->query(
        $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($insert),
        $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
    );


    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `md5()` on the `session_id`? Also, show us the database too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
if ($query->count() == 0) {
```

the `count()` would return the number of rows found, but in a `COUNT(*)` query, you always have one row.

Try this instead:

```
$query = $adapter->execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM sessions WHERE username = '$username' AND session_id = '" . md5(session_id()) . "'");

if($query[0]['cnt'] == 0) { 
  // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: the database table is setup like this   
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username   | char(50)            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| password   | varchar(256)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| active     | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| session_id | char(150)           | NO   |     | NULL    |       |

Comment: would the session_id() be different in different browsers?